# What does _('strong text') mean here

Tags: javascript, function

```
commandTextBold() {
    this.wrapSelectionWithStrings('**', '**', _('strong text'));

}
```

I was working for an opensource project and i cannot understand the third parameter, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the link to project

Comment: Based on the example, `_` is a variable that references a function. `_('strong text')` calls the function passing an argument to it. The return value is passed to `this.wrapSelectionWithStrings`. It's pretty much the same as if some had written `foo(bar('string text'))`, except that the variable/function names are different. Nothing special going on here.

Comment: The third parameter is a function named '_' with accepts a string parameter('strong text') in turn.

Comment: `_()` is a function call could mean many things, maybe its for localization in your Javascript app posting the framework link would help identify what it do.

Comment: Could help if you post the method `wrapSelectionWithStrings` as well

Comment: I've done some investigative work to come up with a plausible solution. Remember you can use any ASCII char (that isn't reserved) in JS function names so you can end up with some funky looking code which is still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method seems to be an internal method to the opensource project (or another project it references) and not the Javascript core framework.

```
commandTextBold() {
    this.wrapSelectionWithStrings('**', '**', _('strong text'));

}
```

Looking at some source code from [markdown.js](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/etalab/udata/file/js/form/markdown.js.html), it seems to reference another project [lingui](https://lingui.js.org/ref/core.html) which is a localisation framework.

Based on this, I assume that depending on the localisation of the application, _('strong text') will return the correct string for the users language for example:

```
EN: _('strong text') returns => 'strong text'
DE: _('strong text') returns => 'starker Text'
IE: _('strong text') returns => 'téacs láidir'
```

The method `wrapSelectionWithStrings` would then be called with the returned string

```
this.wrapSelectionWithStrings('**', '**', 'starker Text');
```

..which in return "looks like" it will return the following value:

```
**starker Text**
```

Answer (score 2):

The `_('strong text')` is function reference to a function named **_** with parameter 'strong text'.